# Pentaho exiting after launch of R script

Tags: r, pentaho

I have been creating a simple transformation using Pentaho with a basic R script. It pulls in a CSV consisting of 2 columns a,b and 3 entries all integers. The preview of data is identical to the data.

The R script, which is central in the process, is as follows:

```
c <- a+b
OUTPUT <-list("c"=c)
```

The flow is as follows:

```
CSV_FILE_INPUT ->- Exceute_R_Script ->- Select_Values
```

The tutorial can be found:

http://dekarlab.de/wp/?p=5

-> followed tutorial exactly

EDIT: Found SpoonDebug - pasted the session details below:

```
    F:\Pentaho 5.1\data-integration>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin\java" "-Xmx512m" "-XX:MaxPermSize=256m" "-Djava.library.path=libswt\win32" "-DKETTLE_HOME=" "-DKETTLE_REPOSITORY=" "-DKETTLE_USER=" "-DKETTLE_PASSWORD=" "-DKETTLE_PLUGIN_PACKAGES=" "-DKETTLE_LOG_SIZE_LIMIT=" "-DKETTLE_JNDI_ROOT=" -jar launcher\pentaho-application-launcher-5.1.0.0-752.jar -lib ..\libswt\win32  /level:Debug 
2014/08/28 10:47:26 - Spoon - Logging is at level : Debugging
2014/08/28 10:47:56 - Spoon - Transformation opened.
2014/08/28 10:47:56 - Spoon - Launching transformation [r_test]...
2014/08/28 10:47:56 - Spoon - Started the transformation execution.
2014/08/28 10:47:57 - r_test - Dispatching started for transformation [r_test]
2014/08/28 10:48:03 - CSV file input.0 - Header row skipped in file 'E:\Downloads\fake_csv.csv'
2014/08/28 10:48:03 - Execute R Script.0 - Loading JRI library from: F:\Pentaho 5.1\data-integration\libswt\win32
2014/08/28 10:48:03 - Execute R Script.0 - R is installed in R_HOME: C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.1\bin\i386
2014/08/28 10:48:03 - CSV file input.0 - Finished processing (I=4, O=0, R=0, W=3, U=0, E=0)
2014/08/28 10:48:03 - Execute R Script.0 - JRI library is found!
2014/08/28 10:48:03 - Execute R Script.0 - rShowMessage
```

Comment: Execute R Script.0 - JRI library is found! Did you copied all what tutorial said? It's obvious that there is missing library.

Comment: @fenix Its saying library is found, as in it is there - it even loads it up! I placed the JRI library in the place suggested - see step 4) 4) Copy JRI library rJava/jri/jri.dll (windows) or rJava/jri/libjri.so (linux) to: data-integration/libswt/{your operation system}

Comment: Whoahh, what a mistake of mine. Set logging to detailed, than update a question please.

Comment: @fenix I've provided all debugging outpuit above. Can't provide logging Pentaho gives as executes as programme exits altogether

Answer (score 0):

To trace the error it is possible to start the transformation without GUI, but using command line tool pan.bat. 
For example:

```
 pan.bat /rep:"Production Repository"
            /trans:"update Customer Dimension"
            /dir:/Dimensions/
            /user:matt
            /pass:somepassword123
            /level:Basic
```

Answer (score 0):

An anonymous user attempted to leave the following:

---

The solution to this problem is to specify R_HOME environment variable like:

```
R_HOME=C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2
```

but **NOT** as

```
R_HOME=C:\Program Files\R\R-3.1.2*bin\x64*
```